# Understanding the onclick property

Tags: javascript, onclick

Could someone please explain the concept of how the 'onlick' property of an element is working, pertaining to its syntax when it is assigned to a function, and its implementation where it is inherited from.

```
const FOO = document.querySelector('.bar');
FOO.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('button clicked');
}
```

One area of confusion is regarding how does the browser know (in the implementation) to treat the onclick property as a click event.

How does assigning the onclick property of an element to a function result in the element being able to listen for click events - as opposed to say assigning a function to any other made up property of that element (whats happening behind the scenes?).

Is every element designed to always listen for click events and by assigning specifically the onclick property to a function it executes that function with the click event?

I am a beginner to programming, JavaScript, and object oriented concepts. I was hoping if someone could offer their insight and explain these concepts in any way.

Many thanks for your time and help

Comment: It's a setter property, that's how it can "detect" the assignment.

Comment: "*Is every element designed to always listen for click events*" - yes. The DOM event handling is quite powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every element is designed to always listen for click events. By writing `Element.onclick = function(){}`, you are assigning a function to the Object (Element)'s onclick property, which will be executed when the element is clicked on. Essentially an Element is an Object, and its properties can be set just like any other Object.

An Object consists of property and value pairs. Consider the following object.

```
var obj = {color: "red"};
```

This Object has only one property, color, which has the value "red". If you were to assign another property to the Object, you could do this:

```
obj.background = "green";//or obj["background"] = "green";
```

You can assign a function as the value of one of an object's properties. An Element's onclick property is always run when it is clicked. When you update the value of it, it replaces the old value, and the new function you provide will be run when the Element is clicked on.